# d3: need different behaviour on click depending on node's class attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a feeling this is a pretty basic misunderstanding on my part.

I'm working from this tree visualisation: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

The original version has the nodes opening and collapsing when the user clicks on a node that has children. I want to make it so that clicking on a node that has no children has some other effect (specifically, I want it to open an image in another window).

So, here's where the on click function is assigned:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("class", function(n) {
        if (n.children) {
            return "inner node"
        } else {
            return "leaf node"
        }
        })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
    .on("click", click);
```

I have added the second class assignment to differentiate between nodes with and without children.

This is my modified click function:

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.attr("class") == "inner node") {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
  } else if (d.attr("class") == "leaf node") {
    // open image
  }
  update(d);
}
```

I added the outer if statement to differentiate between the two kinds of node.

So, currently nothing works when I click. I assume that my 'd.attr("class") == "inner node"' is turning up false, either because the assignment of that class attribute didn't work, or because what I've written is gibberish. It doesn't work when I change it to "node" either, though.

It also occurred to me that the assignment might be scuppered by the fact that all the nodes start off collapsed - so "n.children" might return false, even if there are children. Does collapsing the children affect this?

Any help much appreciated.

------------------------------** EDIT **------------------------------

From playing around a bit, I think I've ascertained that I should have used "d.class", rather than "d.attr('class')". However, this still doesn't make it work. I assume that I have misunderstood what d represents here - is that right?

-----------------------------** EDIT 2 **-----------------------------

OK, my first edit was wrong. However, thanks to prayerslayer, I have changed the code to:

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.children || d._children) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
  } else {
    d3.select( this ).attr("fill", "#CCCCCC");
  }
  update(d);
}
```

It now works. However, contrary to my expectations, it was the text fill that I altered, not the circle fill. Why is that? The text and the circle are distinct areas to click on, but regardless of which one I click on, it is always the text that changes. I assume "this" refers to the node, rather than either the circle or the text specifically, so why did it pick one over the other?

Comment: Could you provide some context with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that contains a minimal example of your problem? I answered already but without more information I can only guess.

Comment: It's very similar to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083. I've put that into a jsFiddle and made some changes to fit my current problem, but the tree graph isn't displaying (sorry, I haven't used jsFiddle before). I imagine I've just misunderstood how jsFiddle works a bit. Here it is:  http://jsfiddle.net/v8S9j/1/. The version on my computer displays the tree, but won't respond to clicks.

Comment: As long as you register your click handler on the group (``svg:g``), ``this`` should refer to the group. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prayerslayer/AXMYh/) for clarification. As a consequence you can't really set a visual attribute via ``this`` as it refers to the group, which itself is invisible. Also note that visual attributes (things you would put in your CSS) are altered via ``.style()``, not ``.attr()``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You're overwriting your class. It should read

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(n) {
    if (n.children) {
        return "node inner node"
    } else {
        return "node leaf node"
    }
    });
```

Note also that `inner` and `node` are two different classes because of the space between them.

---

Short answer: It looks like you're trying to use `.attr()` on something else than a D3 selection.

Longer answer: In D3's functions you have for the most part two parameters: `d` and `i`, where `d` refers to the data associated with your node and `i` is the index of your node.

So, for instance, a click handler on your inner nodes looks like this:

```
d3.selectAll( ".inner.node" ).on( "click", function( d, i ) { /* do somehting */ });
```

`d` is not the SVG element of your node (the "view"), but the data behind it ("the model"). Thus it doesn't have an `.attr()` method. To use this you have to select your view:

```
d3.select( this ).attr(...);
```

I suppose that's where your error stems from.

However I'm also wondering why you have to use the node's class and don't just check for `d.children` in your click handler?

Comment: Well, the honest answer is that I used the class because I found an example of how to do that somewhere and I figured it might work. Am I right in thinking that n is the same as d in that example? If so, I have a problem because d.children in the click function is being used to determine whether the children are collapsed, not whether they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The `d` argument that you're operating on here is the data bound to that particular element, not the element itself. You can access the element as `this` and do the usual D3 operations on it by selecting it. That is, in your `click` handler you could do something like this.

```
function click() {
  if(d3.select(this).attr("class") == "inner node") {
    // do something
  }
}
```

More detail in [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on). The other answer shows you a better way to handle these things though -- you get direct access to the data that you need to distinguish between the different behaviours, so there's no need to proxy through the DOM elements.